# docker-compose simple networking demo

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and docker-compose and I'm trying to understand networking in docker. I have the following docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  app0:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile0
  app1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile1
```

And the Dockerfiles look like

```
FROM: python:latest
```

I'm using a python image because that's what I want for my actual use-case.

I run

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

output:

```
Building app0
Step 1/1 : FROM python:latest
 ---> 3624d01978a1
Successfully built 3624d01978a1
Successfully tagged docker_test_app0:latest
Building app1
Step 1/1 : FROM python:latest
 ---> 3624d01978a1
Successfully built 3624d01978a1
Successfully tagged docker_test_app1:latest

Starting docker_test_app0_1 ... done
Starting docker_test_app1_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_test_app0_1, docker_test_app1_1
docker_test_app0_1 exited with code 0
docker_test_app1_1 exited with code 0
```

From what I've read, docker-compose will create a default network and both containers will be attached to that network and should be able to communicate. I want to come up with a very simple demonstration of this, for example using ping like this:

```
docker-compose run app0 ping app1
```

output:

```
ping: app1: Name or service not known
```

Am I misunderstanding how docker-compose networking works? Should I be able to ping app1 from app0 and vice versa?

running on amazon linux.
docker-compose version version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

Comment: Do these Python containers stay up / start some sort of daemon that keep the container running? Otherwise, if it immediately terminates after starting there is nothing to ping.

Comment: @TobiasK. Yes that was the problem. I created a command in app1 that runs a script with an infinite loop and I was then able to ping app1 from app0! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Added it as an answer too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add something (a script, via `CMD`) to those Python containers that keeps them running, something listening on a port or a simple loop.

Right now they immediately terminate after starting and there is nothing to ping. (The whole container shuts down when its command finished)

Answer (score -1):

Defining services in the docker-composer.yaml file maybe not not enough as if one service will be down the other one won't have information about it's IP address.

You can however create a dependence between them which will for example allow the instance to automatically start app1 service when you start app0.

Set following configuration:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app0:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile0
    depends_on:
      - "app1"
  app1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile1
```

This is a good practice in case you want services to communicate between each other.

Comment: I did this and still get the same result. Can you actually run this?

Comment: The only useful effect of `depends_on:` is that `docker-compose up app0` will also start `app1`.  You don't specifically need it for inter-container communication.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you for your input, I've updated my answer. It still maybe helpful in similar case